# Most efficient way to concatenate list within list without a loop

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

```
public class Unicorn
{
    public List<int> Numbers { get; set; }
}

unicorns.Add(new Unicorn() { Numbers = {1, 2, 3} } );
unicorns.Add(new Unicorn() { Numbers = {4, 5, 6} } );
unicorns.Add(new Unicorn() { Numbers = {7, 8, 9} } );
```

What's the most efficient way in c# 4 to concatenate all the lists into one list of {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 } ?

Preferably (ideally; by preference; if one had a choice) no loops and Linq-less. I tinkered around with .FindAll, but it's not digging it.

Comment: What's wrong with loops and LINQ?

Comment: No loops and no LINQ?  What on earth are you expecting?

Comment: Why "linq-less"? A SelectMany call would solve it perfectly.

Comment: No linq, no loops, and some flavor of efficiency?

Comment: If you're using C# 4 without Linq, you're not really using C# 4.

Comment: How you can imagine an array traversing without loop? At least you have to do simple `while()` loop and iterating using `GetEnumerator()` and `MoveNext()`

Comment: You guys are killing me! Linq == Performance loss. And loops == many more lines of codes than are necessary.

Comment: @Levitikon: "Linq == Performance loss" - citation needed.

Comment: Each LINQ provider implementation is optimized for a specific application (SQL, Objects, Xml, etc).

Comment: @Joe "Linq == Performance loss" compared to array blitting. You heard it here first.

Comment: @Joe, http://www.nichesoftware.co.nz/blog/200909/linq-vs-loop-performance or http://www.schnieds.com/2009/03/linq-vs-foreach-vs-for-loop-performance.html

Comment: HEY ALL :) OP said **preferrably** no LINQ... so I propose to stop downvoting

Comment: "If profiling shows you that looping is the dominant factor in your code - that saving 22 nanoseconds per loop is going to be significant, then go ahead and use foreach instead of Linq.

Out here in the real world though, I don't think the difference is significant for 99.99% of code.
Conclusion

Selecting foreach instead of Linq is a micro-optimization that will almost certainly make no material difference."

Comment: oh and "The test was run with Visual Studio 2008 beta - this means it was running against a debug build of the .NET framework, and it's well known that Microsoft leaves debugging tests and other monitoring tools active in those builds. That's why the EULA on betas prohibits performance testing."

Comment: Seriously, 5 down votes?? I didn't intend to offend any Linqers out there. I did say preferably you know. I appreciate you feed back, but dang..

Comment: It is not an offense.  It is a bad question.  You are placing up an arbitrary requirement on what would otherwise be a very easy problem to solve.  If you had a legitimate reason for them it would be a different story.  However, all this will do it make your code harder to read and maintain while adding no benefit.  You might as well be asking how to add two numbers together without using addition.

Comment: The most *efficient* way would be to not put it in a list of lists in the first place.

Comment: It is pitch black. You are likely to be eaten by a grue.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
List<int> theInts = unicorns.SelectMany(unicorn => unicorn.Numbers).ToList();
```

---

Without measuring, the only thing in here that gives me pause from a performance perspective is the .ToList

If there are a TON of numbers, it's possible that ToList may repeatedly re-allocate its backing array.  In order to escape this behavior, you have to have some idea about how many Numbers to expect.

```
List<int> theInts = new List<int>(expectedSize);
theInts.AddRange(unicorns.SelectMany(unicorn => unicorn.Numbers));
```

Comment: Right...that's the obvious answer.  Except, in a fit of insanity, the OP doesn't want it.

Comment: But... the question specifically says linq-less.  You've just allowed and accepted an answer that was specifically contrary to the question.  Had you not mentioned that, others would have posted a linq solution.

Comment: When someone says, "I'd like the soup, hold the bowl.", there are three obvious responses: "Here's your soup with bowl" or "No soup for you, Next!" or "Here's your soup with no bowl, oh - I guess you didn't really want that."  I merely chose the most helpful.

Comment: @Dan Andrews, we live in such a dynamic world that we can only strive for what we want. I did write "Preferably linq-less", but that doesn't mean I will only accept a linq-less solution. You have to remember, I'm inquiring the subject - so I'm not aware if there even is a good linq-less solution. Apparently there wasn't, so I'm flexible enough to adapt. I'm really not sure why everyone is so bitter about this question.

Comment: @ Ultimately you were looking for dialog per your last response.  Therefore, this isn't an answerable question per SO guidelines: "If your motivation for asking the question is “I would like to participate in a discussion about ______”, then you should not be asking here. (You are more than welcome to have such discussions in our real time web chat.) However, if your motivation is “I would like others to explain ______ to me”, then you are probably OK."... "Expert programmers interested in professional discussions on software development, ask on Programmers." via stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask

Comment: Comment about the question on the question.  Comment about the answer on the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a solution that fully meets your requirements: **No** Linq and **no** loop - I'm pretty sure you do not want to use this code though:

```
List<Unicorn> unicorns = new List<Unicorn>();
unicorns.Add(new Unicorn() { Numbers = new List<int>{1, 2, 3} } );
unicorns.Add(new Unicorn() { Numbers = new List<int> { 4, 5, 6 } });
unicorns.Add(new Unicorn() { Numbers = new List<int> { 7, 8, 9 } });

List<int> numbers = new List<int>();
int count = 0;

AddUnicorn: 
if(count < unicorns.Count)
{
    numbers.AddRange(unicorns[count++].Numbers);
    goto AddUnicorn;
}
```

Comment: goto the start of the loop :)

Comment: AddRange also internally operates by a loop.

Answer (score 2):

Your requirements are quite out of the ordinary, but I guess you can always write:

```
var numbers = new List<int>();
unicorns.ForEach(unicorn => numbers.AddRange(unicorn.Numbers));
```

[ForEach()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwabdf9z.aspx) arguably qualifies as "LINQ-less", since it's a genuine member of `List<T>`, not an extension method on `IEnumerable<T>`, and it actually [predates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwabdf9z%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) LINQ itself.

Comment: ForEach may be LINQ-less, but both ForEach and AddRange use loops, so... :)

Comment: @David, internally, yes, as do `Zip()`, `Skip()`, `Count()`, and of course `SelectMany()` :)

Answer (score 1):

Using .NET 4.0's Zip operator:

```
     var sums = b.Zip(a, (x, y) => x + y)
        .Concat(b.Skip(a.Count()));
```

If you want to generalize this, check which has more elements and use that as the "b" above

Comment: You think this improves on `SelectMany`?

Comment: @KirkWoll user does not want a loop so just giving an extra option to use. It worked for me.

Comment: Right, and OP didn't want LINQ either, which this violates.  So if you're going to use LINQ at all, you should use David's solution.  IMO, this solution is completely unreadable.